# Values not being received by functions

Tags: c++, function

So I'm trying to make a program that takes some random number of entered seconds and converts it to Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds. I had to use symbolic constants to define the hours in a day, minutes in an hour, and seconds in a minute. I passed the value through but it's not being recieved so I end up with some huge negative number. Here's the code. If anyone can tell me where the problem lies I would be ever thankful.

I used the random bit of code in the function definitions code to oput total seconds to see if it was being recieved and it's not.

```
#ifndef SECONDS_H_
#define SECONDS_H_

#define HOURS_IN_DAY 24
#define MINUTES_IN_HOUR 60
#define SECONDS_IN_MINUTES 60

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Seconds
{
private:
    long totalSeconds;
public:
    Seconds();
    ~Seconds(){};
    Seconds(int totalSeconds);
    void Seconds::convertSeconds(int &days, int &hours, int &minutes, int &seconds);
};

#endif
```

...

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "seconds.h"

#define HOURS_IN_DAY 24
#define MINUTES_IN_HOUR 60
#define SECONDS_IN_MINUTE 60

Seconds::Seconds(int totalSeconds)
{
    totalSeconds = totalSeconds;
}

void Seconds::convertSeconds(int &days, int &hours, int &minutes, int &seconds)
{   
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Total Seconds: " << totalSeconds;
    cout << endl;

    days = totalSeconds / MINUTES_IN_HOUR / SECONDS_IN_MINUTE / HOURS_IN_DAY;
    hours = (totalSeconds / MINUTES_IN_HOUR / SECONDS_IN_MINUTE) % HOURS_IN_DAY;
    minutes = (totalSeconds / MINUTES_IN_HOUR) % SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
    seconds = (totalSeconds % SECONDS_IN_MINUTE);

}
```

...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include "seconds.h"

#define HOURS_IN_DAY 24
#define MINUTES_IN_HOUR 60
#define SECONDS_IN_MINUTES 60

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int totalSeconds;
    int days = 0, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0;

    cout << "Enter a random massive amount of seconds: ";
    cin >> totalSeconds;

    Seconds sec(totalSeconds);

    sec.convertSeconds(days, hours, minutes, seconds);

    cout << "That is equivalent to " << days << " days, " << hours << " hours, " << minutes << " minutes, " << seconds << " seconds." << endl;

    cout << "Press any key to continue...";
    cin.sync();
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value for 'seconds' do you provide as input?  Have you tried to print it out or show it in a debugger?

Comment: Also when you declare the class you shouldn't use the class name in the method declaration: `void Seconds::convertSeconds`. Some compilers warn about this, some others won't compile your stuff depending on the compiler settings. And its a matter of taste but if you have a lot of func parameters then in my opinion its better to pack these values into a struct and pass a struct reference or struct const reference to the function. Its easier to add more parameters later. Although it takes more lines to perform a function call the code becomes more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
Seconds::Seconds(int totalSeconds)
{
    totalSeconds = totalSeconds;
}
```

The function parameter `totalSeconds` shadows the class member, so this code is like doing `x = x;`, it has no effect on `this->totalSeconds`.

To fix this either use different variable name, or preferably use constructor initialization syntax:

```
Seconds::Seconds(long totalSeconds)
   : totalSeconds(totalSeconds)
{
}
```

In this version, shadowing does not occur because the constructor initialization lists are smart.

Comment: Shadowing does not occur in the case of the initialization list because the `totalSeconds` parameter could not legally appear in that context, not because the initialization list is smart. It's the same compiler.

Comment: Preferably use the initializer *and* a different name.  I know that C++ programmers should know that using the same name will work with an initializer, but why make someone even have to think about it for a moment?  Just throw an underscore after the argument name (or leave it off if your naming convention for member variables uses a trailing underscore).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that the problem might be [Integer Overflow](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/)?